# Apache solr : Put Multiple Field values together

Tags: apache, solr, custom-field-type

I want to group on multiple fields(5 fields). In solr for that I dont know what to do!. But I got Idea that if I merge all my five fields together as single field value with delimnator char is "~". then if I group on that field, I can get result.

But for this merging all fields together what I have to do, anyone plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to group by multiple fields, this is probably the easiest way to do, but it requires that you have a *static* group clause i.e. the fields for grouping are pre-determined.

In order to do this, you need to create a new field in your `schema.xml` and map it to a concatenated value of the fields *at the time of indexing*.

If you are using DataImportHandler, you could use the [`ScriptTransformer`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to compute this field's value.

Comment: can I use templateTransformers to do that?

Comment: yes, TemplateTransformer is better, unless you need to compute any field.

Comment: what do you mean by "static group clause"?

Comment: I meant that you do not have to change the `group` clause at querytime.